# Google Apps Script: Endpoint Not Found

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm experiencing an issue in my Google Docs add-on running as a web app where users logged in to multiple Google accounts at the same time, and then when they try to authorize with a third party application their access token is getting saved to the wrong Google account.

My idea to get around this is to check the current user's email by passing in the authorizing user's email in a state parameter and then reconstruct the redirect URL to include an authuser parameter with the email of the correct account, and then redirecting to that end point. However, I'm having issues with creating a new redirect URL that actually works.

My regular OAuth redirect brings me back to my script at the `/exec` endpoint. Inside my `doGet()` I'm checking if the state parameter equals the value from `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`. If it does not then I construct a new redirect URL pointed to my `/exec` endpoint, except I also add an authuser parameter along with a redir parameter that tells that app to not try and build a new redirect the next time through `doGet()`.  Then, I output an HTML page called userAuth. The userAuth page contains a link for the user to click using the new redirect containing authuser. The problem is, when you click on this link you're greeted by a, "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist." error message.

What is happening to my `/exec` endpoint that is making it not exist the second time I try to request it? Is there a better way I should be going about this?

**UPDATE:** I've discovered that my `/exec` endpoint is not found only if I send an `authuser` parameter value that differs from the one is currently authorized with Google. Am I misunderstanding what the `authuser` parameter does? I thought that since the user was signed in to both Google accounts, `authuser` would designate which account was using the add-on.

My `doGet()` code is below. Thanks for any help!

```
function doGet(request) {
  var HTMLToOutput;
  if (request.parameters.state != Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() && 
         !request.parameters.redir) {
    var authuser = request.parameters.state;
    var newRedir = AUTH_REDIRECT_URI;
    newRedir = newRedir + "?code="+ request.parameters.code + "&redir=true&authuser="
               + authuser;
    setPrivateCache('newRedir', newRedir);
    HTMLToOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("userAuth");
  } else if (request.parameters.code) {
    HTMLToOutput = upgradeAuthCode(request.parameters.code + "");
  } else if (request.parameters.error == 'access_denied') {
    HTMLToOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("accessDenied");
  }
  return HTMLToOutput;
}
```

Comment: Does the 2nd account, the one that generated the 404 error message, have access to the web app? For example, if you are using the /dev endpoint then only editors of the script will be able to access the webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, that was it. Thanks, Eric! I was developing and running the script off a test domain that only allowed access to the web app from within the domain. The second account I was using to test with was from gmail.

The reason why I hadn't thought about the gmail account not having access to the web app initially was because I successfully hit the `/exec` endpoint and was shown the `userAuth` html page. But, when I hit the link to go back to `/exec` I was shown the 404.

In hindsight, this is obvious, because the first time I hit `/exec` it was with the first account that had access to the web app. The second time I hit `/exec` it was with the second account that did not have access to the web app.

Once I moved the Apps Script outside of the testing domain, and deployed the web app to allow access to Anyone, the redirect worked correctly.